# PostgreSQL to MS SQL Server bridge/gateway

Tags: sql-server, postgresql, connectivity

We have an application that only supports PostgreSQL as a backend, but we have our whole infrastructure already setup with SQL Server, and we would like to keep using it instead of having new PostgreSQL services.

Is there a software product that would work between the application and SQL Server that would translate PostgreSQL calls to SQL Server calls?

I read about "Foreign data wrappers" in Postgres but doesn't seem to be the same thing. And any other search I do leads to answers about migrations.

Comment: Unless the application vendor (who seems to insist on PostgreSQL anyway) supports such a tool, any solution is likely going to void any support contract you got. Ask the vendor for advice, maybe a managed PostgreSQL would work just fine?

Comment: FDW in PostgreSQL doesn't seem like a solution.  You would need a running PostgreSQL server to use them, and that is (apparently) what you want to avoid.

Comment: What version of PostgreSQL and SQL Server? What edition of SQL Server? In older versions of SQL Server, it was possible to enable replication from PostgreSQL. Otherwise, a Linked Server may be able to suffice depending on your use cases. What's your goals with using this data?

Comment: @J.D. It's PostgreSQL 15 and SQL Server 2019. Gonna take a look to Linked Server, thanks

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned in the comments, a [Linked Server](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/linked-servers/linked-servers-database-engine?view=sql-server-ver16) object may be able to suffice for your use cases:

> Linked servers enable the SQL Server Database Engine and Azure SQL Managed Instance to read data from the remote data sources and execute commands against the remote database servers (for example, OLE DB data sources) outside of the instance of SQL Server. Typically linked servers are configured to enable the Database Engine to execute a Transact-SQL statement that includes tables in another instance of SQL Server, or another database product such as Oracle. Many types OLE DB data sources can be configured as linked servers, including third-party database providers and Azure CosmosDB.

They are definitely creatable between PostgreSQL and SQL Server (especially the versions you mentioned) and would live at the server instance level within your SQL Server. That makes it accessible from any database in your SQL Server instance. Here's the [docs on how to create a Linked Server](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/linked-servers/create-linked-servers-sql-server-database-engine?view=sql-server-ver16).

With a Linked Server you'd be able to query your PostgreSQL database in realtime from your SQL Server, using standard T-SQL (SQL Server) syntax. You can create Views, Procedures, and other database objects that reference the PostgreSQL Tables and Views through the Linked Server as if they were local objects. There are some gotchas with Linked Servers, generally revolving around performance, too. In some cases, the entire data being queried is brought across the link locally before it's filtered down. There's ways to mitigate this with proper query writing. Please read the docs carefully.

They are a pretty standard way to access a remote data source and pretty much are able to bridge the gap between almost any other database.

---

Also, this shouldn't void your support contract with the vendor of your PostgreSQL app, because it's non-invasive. The changes are only made on your SQL Server instance's side.